# Simple DVD burner software

Tags: windows, optical-media

I'm looking for a simple, easy-to-use (like with good UI), reliable, simple DVD writer software for windows, which is capable of creating DVD compilations from the file system, with no or minimum bloatware (like the opposite of Nero Burning ROM) and minimum effect on your system configuration (like automatically registered file associations, etc), if a portable version would be available, that's an extra.

Comment: DVD compilations -> audio or video compilations?

Comment: Video compilations. However I'm pretty sure that software, which capable of doing this, usually could do both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/). The .NET Framework should be present in your system.

- free
- all operating systems from Microsoft Windows 2000 SP4 onwards are supported.
- CDs and DVDs
- burns [video compilations](https://cdburnerxp.se/help/Data/create-video-dvd)

It does not install any adware or similar malicious components, but the controversial [OpenCandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCandy) module is included in the main installer. You can [go to the download page](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) and click on "More download options" to get a version without OpenCandy.

[image]

Comment: This is asking for a VIDEO_TS folder. What if you only have a MPG file?